# MySQL on OSX Sierra can't start: The server quit without updating PID file

Tags: mysql, macos

Several problems with mysql since last Sierra Update.
Reinstalled several times with brew or mysql dmg and followd many many "solutions" on SO.

Finally it worked but after a Mac Crash, I face the same problem.

- MySql won't start from preference panel
- Mysql won't start from terminal: Can't connect through /tmp/mysql.sock...**of course**, mysqld is not running
- trying to start mysqld:

  sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start

  ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/My-iMac.local.pid)

  sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld several errors and shutdown

a bit stuck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just tried this

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe
mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/My-iMac.local.err'.
Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/My-iMac.local.pid ended
```

And now looking at error log, the explanation is clear:

```
tail /usr/local/mysql/data/My-iMac.local.err
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
```

So I added in my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery = 1
```

and now it starts!

It was probably due to previous Mac Crash

Answer (score 3):

In my case the owner of the data folder was changed after an OS update.

After fixing this with …

```
sudo chown -R mysql /usr/local/mysql/data
```

… everything worked like a charm again.

Answer (score -1):

Oh, I feel your pain. I've had this happen many times. Stopping the processes didn't always work. To solve this I simply went into System Preferences and MySQL... stop the process from there and try to restart.